# How to get the lag of a column in a Spark streaming dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, spark-structured-streaming

I have data streaming into my Spark Scala application in this format

```
id    mark1 mark2 mark3 time
uuid1 100   200   300   Tue Aug  8 14:06:02 PDT 2017
uuid1 100   200   300   Tue Aug  8 14:06:22 PDT 2017
uuid2 150   250   350   Tue Aug  8 14:06:32 PDT 2017
uuid2 150   250   350   Tue Aug  8 14:06:52 PDT 2017
uuid2 150   250   350   Tue Aug  8 14:06:58 PDT 2017
```

I have it read into columns id, mark1, mark2, mark3 and time. The time is converted to datetime format as well.
I want to get this grouped by id and get the lag for mark1 which gives the previous row's mark1 value.
Something like this:

```
id    mark1 mark2 mark3 prev_mark time
uuid1 100   200   300   null      Tue Aug  8 14:06:02 PDT 2017
uuid1 100   200   300   100       Tue Aug  8 14:06:22 PDT 2017
uuid2 150   250   350   null      Tue Aug  8 14:06:32 PDT 2017
uuid2 150   250   350   150       Tue Aug  8 14:06:52 PDT 2017
uuid2 150   250   350   150       Tue Aug  8 14:06:58 PDT 2017
```

Consider the dataframe to be markDF. I have tried:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("uuid").orderBy("timestamp")
val newerDF = newDF.withColumn("prev_mark", lag("mark1", 1, null).over(window))`
```

which says non time windows cannot be applied on streaming/appending datasets/frames.

I have also tried:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("uuid").orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(-10, 10)
val newerDF = newDF.withColumn("prev_mark", lag("mark1", 1, null).over(window))
```

To get a window for few rows which did not work either. The streaming window something like:
`window("timestamp", "10 minutes")`
cannot be used to send over the lag. I am super confused on how to do this. Any help would be awesome!!

Comment: Doing ` lag` every batch or whole stream data?

Answer (score -4):

I would advise you to change the `time` column into `String` as

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------------------+
|id   |mark1|mark2|mark3|time                        |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------------------+
|uuid1|100  |200  |300  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:02 PDT 2017|
|uuid1|100  |200  |300  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:22 PDT 2017|
|uuid2|150  |250  |350  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:32 PDT 2017|
|uuid2|150  |250  |350  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:52 PDT 2017|
|uuid2|150  |250  |350  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:58 PDT 2017|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------------------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mark1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- mark2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- mark3: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
```

After that doing the following should work

```
df.withColumn("prev_mark", lag("mark1", 1).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("time")))
```

Which will give you output as

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------------------+---------+
|id   |mark1|mark2|mark3|time                        |prev_mark|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------------------+---------+
|uuid1|100  |200  |300  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:02 PDT 2017|null     |
|uuid1|100  |200  |300  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:22 PDT 2017|100      |
|uuid2|150  |250  |350  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:32 PDT 2017|null     |
|uuid2|150  |250  |350  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:52 PDT 2017|150      |
|uuid2|150  |250  |350  |Tue Aug  8 14:06:58 PDT 2017|150      |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: This would not work as I the dataframe is a streaming dataframe

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: the over function does not non time based windows

Comment: thats why i am saying to change into string. :) I think you didn't read my answer correctly

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I am not able to solve the issue with your solution. You sure did this on a streaming df?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RameshMaharjan . It seems currently, spark at 2.3 does not support advanced windowing/analytic functions. Moreover, it does not support windowing on non time based columns - which is a major drawback.